# How do I get rid of the CreationName Error in my SSIS package in SSMS?

Tags: ssis, ssms-2014

I have created an SSIS-Package, which is supposed to import Data from Flatfiles (txt. Files) into a Database. 
When I execute the package via Visual Studio (Enterprise, 2015), there are no problems and everything works just fine. 
The problem occurs when I deploy the package into SSMS (Express, 2014). When I execute the package from SSMS, I get an Error (no idea if there is an Error Code or where to find it) concerning the property "CreationName". SSMS doesn't seem to give me any other information. 
In the package are 5 scripts, which all do the same but with different flatfiles. 
They all get this CreationName Error.

Has anyone any idea on how to fix it or the source of the problem?

[image]

Comment: Is CreationName a variable or step in your SSIS package?

Comment: The CreationName is apparantly a generated variable; i've never heard of it before i had this problem: 
msdn has some info about it, but it doesnt help me really (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.idtsname.creationname?view=sqlserver-2017#Microsoft_SqlServer_Dts_Runtime_IDTSName_CreationName) 

Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: Check your script tasks to see if your calling that anywhere, there is a lot of example code in the script tasks, and maybe some of it was uncommitted somehow so check to ensure it is not being used anywhere.  Also there are lots of places things can hide in your code like in Expressions inside nested options inside things.  You can open your project file with notepad++ and search for that variable name to see if and where you are using it (hard to read but it works).

Comment: What language is that (German or Dutch is my best guess) - I do not understand it? Is that the All Executions or All Validations report? Please provide the actual error from the All Execution report - it will be highlighted red on the far left with a Message Type of OnError.

Comment: @Brad I've tried that, but apart from me being able to add the variable in ssis, which i tried (has apparently no effect) i couldnt find it :/ 
@J Weezy its german, my apologies. It is the all executions report. not sure how i can upload a picture  in the comments :[

Comment: Is there something in the job or settings itself that is trying to read or do something with that variable?

Comment: Based on the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/install-windows/install-integration-services?view=sql-server-2017) `SSIS is not included with the Express edition of SQL Server.` I didn't understand how you `deploy the package into SSMS (Express, 2014).`??!!

Comment: @Hadi No it's not, but it is in Visual Studio Enterprise, and i deploy it from there; and it gets deployed onto a Enterprise SQL Server; just my SSMS is in Express Edition :) 

To all the people who've tried to help me here; I thank you so much! But i have to say i found that the issue isnt about the creation name, but it's about the SSIS package trying to reach it's source on my virtual drive. idk why it would do that, but i will put some research into it before asking again! :)

Comment: @HutchenMan when you solves the issue write the solution as answer and accept it. Good luck

Comment: @Hadi thanks mate! any idea how to mark theis problem as solved? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved the problem, but it had nothing to do with the creationname apparently - i made some wrong settings in my sql agent + i made it work by deplying it from my hard drive instead of the virtual drive. I also had a typo in one of the scripts :x Idk why it had problems with the virtual drive though; maybe it was an authentication problem. Still THANK YOU ALL SO MUCH! You guys kinda brought me there :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what's written on the attached image, but I would disable 4 out of 5 components then run through the job. If there's no error than disable 3 out of 5 and run it again...you get the point. Obviously this has to be done in a non-prod environment. I believe that will help you narrow down the problem within your package. Maybe you can debug from thereon?

Comment: Hi Guys, i solved the problem, but it had nothing to do with the creationname apparently - i made some wrong settings in my sql agent + i made it work by deplying it from my hard drive instead of the virtual drive. I also had a typo in one of the scripts :x Idk why it had problems with the virtual drive though; maybe it was an authentication problem.
Still THANK YOU ALL SO MUCH! You guys kinda brought me there :)